# Pass several values from one webPage to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I want to take the information in each of theses text-boxes to another web-form page. Theses text-boxes are in a table and I want the values to show in the next page in the given labels

```
string txt = TextBox1.Text;
Session["first"] = txt;

string txt1 = TextBox2.Text;
Session["second"] = txt1;

string txt2 = TextBox3.Text;
Session["third"] = txt2;

string txt3 = TextBox4.Text;
Session["fourth"] = txt3;

string txt4 = TextBox5.Text;
Session["fifth"] = txt4;

string txt5 = TextBox6.Text;
Session["sixth"] = txt5;

string txt6 = TextBox7.Text;
Session["seventh"] = txt6;

string txt7 = TextBox8.Text;
Session["eighth"] = txt7;

string txt8 = TextBox9.Text;
Session["nineth"] = txt8;
```

Comment: works fine but this is not a good coding practice

Comment: whats the issue here?

Comment: Your title says "more than one session", but you're not explaining anything about why, how etc this relates to the text. You also have no question in your actual text. Please edit and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more session variables if you want. But a better approach is to use a list:

```
MyList.Add(txt);
MyList.Add(txt1);
MyList.Add(txt2);
.......

Session["MyValues"] = MyList;
```

Retrieve it on other pages like:

```
MyList = Session["MyValues"] as List<string>;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You could store each information in a session var - but IMO it is unnecesseary unless you need the information in some other pages too.

If you just want to access information on the next page you may use property [PreviousPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and a [postBackUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl(v=vs.110).aspx) of the button. I did a small example demonstrating how to make use of it.

**page1.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    Enter data <asp:TextBox ID="txtData" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" PostBackUrl="page2.aspx"/>
</div>
</form>
```

**page2.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    You have entered: <asp:Label ID="lblData" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

**page2.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblData.Text = ((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("txtData")).Text;
}
```

On the other hand if you want to gather informations over several "pages" you may consider using a [wizard control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Create all values as object:

```
obj.Name = "Kerollos Adel";
obj.Class = "150";
```

Then add object to session and get it in the second pave.

Comment: This is not an answer at all! Please clarify what object class is, how to add several values aso..